# checking dynamically created checkbox states

Tags: .net, vb.net, dynamic, checkbox

I know this question has been answered before but i cant seem to get an answer that will work with what i want which is to be able to check if my dynamically created check boxes have been checked, I need to be able to check each check box individually.

Here is my code for creating the check box

```
Private Sub CreateCheckbox(ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, text As String, ByVal id As Integer)
    Dim btnYes As System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
    btnYes = New System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
    btnYes.AutoSize = True
    btnYes.TabStop = True
    btnYes.Name = "CheckBox" + id
    btnYes.TabIndex = id
    btnYes.Parent = Panel1
    btnYes.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(81, 17)
    btnYes.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(x, y)
    btnYes.TabIndex = 1
    btnYes.Text = text
    Button1.TabIndex = Button1.TabIndex + 1
    Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(btnYes)
End Sub
```

i need something like

```
for i as integer = 0 to id step 1
 if checkbox(i).checked = true then
   'Do Something
 end if
next
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add `handler` for your dynamically created `checkboxes`, The given code will create a `check box` and by the way it will add `checkedChanged` event handler for the same.

```
Private Sub CreateCheckbox(ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, text As String, ByVal id As Integer)
    Dim btnYes As System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
    btnYes = New System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
    ...............
    ...............

    Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(btnYes)

    'Now here add a common handler for your created checkbox
     AddHandler btnYes.CheckedChanged addressOf CommonCheckedChangeHandler
End Sub
```

The following procedure will get invoked according to the event(checkedchanged) we added above. we can access the particular checkbox by using the parameter `sender`

```
private sub CommonCheckedChangeHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
   ' This method will be invoked when your dynamically
   ' created check box's checked state got changed
End sub
```

**Edit 1:**

Use the following code to traverse inside the `panel` to check your `checkboxes`

```
For Each chkBox In Panel1.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)()
  'Check here whether your check boxes are checked true/false
Next
```

**Edit 2:**

OfType belongs to `LINQ`, if you dont want the above try this code

```
for i as integer = 0 to id step 1
 if Ctype(panel1.controls("CheckBox" & i), checkbox).checked = true then
   'Do Something
 end if
next
```

Comment: Ok i tried your method but how do i get it to execute code not when the check box is checked but when a button is pressed. ie button pressed it checks which check boxes are checked and executes code.

Comment: i get the error 'OfType' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection'. This is why i asked the question as no matter what i try i cant get a solution that works.

Comment: I dont think that the updated code doesnt work, because i tested it before i posting that.! comment the code that you have tried by using the new update, if you wish. It may help to solve your problem.

Comment: ok i get no errors at compilation but when i execute the code without a break point above it i get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" however if i put a break point above if Ctype(panel1.controls("CheckBox" & i), checkbox).checked = true then and wait about a second it works fine. any thoughts

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26520/discussion-between-crackruckles-and-gloier-tech)